# Joomla Version 1.5.26 module php errors

Tags: php, joomla, undefined, notice

hoping somebody can help,

having an issue with a news posting section on a Joomla site: http://buffalowingsandrings.com/#/in-the-news - You'll see if you scroll down, that there are lots of empty fields. We only want to display 10 news stories and we are unsure why these blank ones are appearing.

I didn't build the site, I just have access and have to fix for a client.

After turning on the error reporting we see the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$created in
>   /home/content/16/11371716/html/templates/bwr_pages/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php
>   on line 3 11 September 2014
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$readmore_link in
>   /home/content/16/11371716/html/templates/bwr_pages/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php
>   on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$title in
>   /home/content/16/11371716/html/templates/bwr_pages/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php
>   on line 9
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /home/content/16/11371716/html/components/com_content/views/category/view.html.php
>   on line 217
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$attribs in
>   /home/content/16/11371716/html/components/com_content/views/category/view.html.php
>   on line 225
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$id in
>   /home/content/16/11371716/html/plugins/content/vote.php on line 23

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would help to put a descriptive title. Also what have you tried? What research have you done?

Answer (score 0):

I may guess that those empty block's might come from inefficient code for the view of this menu item for the extra content settings like intro items or link items.

You can try this:

Go in the menu manager, locate the menu item for this blog page ( in-the-news ) and check its parameters basic section (on the right) for how many articles are set to be displayed.

How many leading and intro articles, how many links... 
Maybe you would like to set links to 0 and also experiment with the leading / intro articles count number and see how this affecting the front-end.

Please note also that changes may not appear right after your changes, so clear joomla's and browser cache when checking in the front-end.

Comment: And Elin is right in his comment above... You should demonstrate that you have tried on your own to fix the issue. Hope that you won't sell this kind of service to your client.